# Mirroring UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

I have a `UIView` with a transparent background, and some buttons. I would like to capture the drawing of the view, shrink it, and redraw (mirror) it elsewhere on the screen. (On top of another view.) The buttons can change, so it isn't static.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Check a nice sample code http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2011/06/dynamic-view-reflection-using.html following WWDC sessions. It uses

```
CAReplicatorLayer
```

for reflection, pretty easy to implement and looks really smooth and impressive.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea will be to get a `UIView`'s `layer` to draw itself into a context and then grab a `UIImage` out of it.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);

[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You will also need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: So then I would scale the UIImage and draw it where I want it? And would it preserve the transparency? Thanks.

Comment: Yes and Yes it should preserve the transparency.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a `CGContext` directly, without the overhead if a UIImage?

Comment: Do you have issues? or are you trying to prematurely optimize?

Comment: I'd probably go for the simplest thing that works, until it no longer works (in your case until you can prove it is slowing you down enough) then go fix it.

Comment: Okay, I think this would work, except for `renderInContext` doesn't capture everything. (Such as `UIButton`s.) See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860490/capturing-image-of-uiview-renderincontext-not-working-properly

Comment: Okay, so the problem actually isn't `renderInContext`, but instead is my implementation. I wasn't updating my second view. See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8865207/542687

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to *capture the drawing* (from what you describe, it seems unlikely that you need an image), create another instance of the view and apply a transform. Something like...

```
UIView* original [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:originalFrame];
UIView* copy = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:copyFrame];

// Scale down 50% and rotate 45 degrees
//
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
copy.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, M_PI_4);

[someSuperView addSubview:original];
[someSuperView addSubview:copy];

// release, etc.
```

I added the rotation just to show that you can do a variety of different things with transformations.

Comment: And then how do I draw the contents of the original `UIView` to the smaller one?

Comment: If it is an instance of the same class, wouldn't it draw the same once added to the superview?

Comment: But how are the two `UIView`s connected? I don't see why `copy` would draw the contents of `original` in your sample code.

Comment: Recreating a view hierarchy is surely more expensive then `... [getting an] image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context`

Comment: @Jay, the connection is that they are the same class ie. `UIView` or it could be some subclass of `UIView` (maybe `UIBallView`, or something) Therefore, since they are the same class, they share the same drawing logic and will draw the same.

Comment: @nloko But if I tapped a button in the `original` view, it would not result in that action being drawn in the `copy` view. This method would work if the `original` view was static, but it is not.

Comment: @Jay, yes, the views would need to be synchronized in some way whenever the `original` view (or any of its subviews) was redrawn. I think running with either of the approaches mentioned here could work for you.

Comment: @Paul.s: On what grounds? Copying and potentially scaling thousands of pixels is an expensive operation; well-optimized original drawing in both places may very well be cheaper.

Comment: Why use a transform rather than simply change the frame?

Comment: For this to work you would also need to have all your subviews auto-resizing masks set correctly.

Comment: @PeterHosey I guess it depends on how complicated the view hierarchy is. By the sounds of it there is a least one transparent container view and then several buttons which all need to be allocated, initialised and who knows what other code has been chucked in the mix, + surely the net result will be the same size backing store that the `UIImage` is created from? I'm no expert so all of that could well be all a lot cheaper than an image, would be interesting to know your thoughts.

Comment: @Paul.s: Creating the views only needs to happen once, whereas copying one view's image to the other would need to happen for every drawing pass. Moreover, the layer-backed nature of views in Cocoa Touch means that you wouldn't need to redraw all of the views most of the time.

Comment: @nloko In your example, Would I need to transform all of the buttons in the `copy` `UIView`, or would just transforming the view be good enough?