# Capturing image of UIView (renderInContext not working properly)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, calayer

I am trying to capture an image of a `UIView` with `renderInContex`, but it does not fully capture all of the subviews. (For example, it doesn't capture the words in a `UITextView`, and it doesn't capture a `UIButton` at all.)

What can I use instead?

Edit:
The problem actually isn't `renderInContext`, but instead is my implementation. See my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865207/542687

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like `renderInContext` might work if you adjust the graphics context first.  Try this if you haven't already done so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869804

Comment: Thanks, but I still got the same result.

Comment: Okay, so the problem actually isn't `renderInContext`, but instead is my implementation. See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8865207/542687